# Updated core-data values not retaining after App killed and re-launched

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, restkit

- I have update a NSModelObject and saved using the following code, the changes are saved and updated in app.

  ```
  do {
      try managedObjectContext.save()
  } catch {
      print("Could not save")
  }
  ```
- But when I kill the app and re-launch it the updated changes are lost.

**Note:**

- I am using Restkit for mapping those data in db
- I also check "**saveContext()**" in AppDelegate which is called from "**applicationWillTerminate**"

What am I doing it wrong ? Why the contents are not saved in core data permanently ?

Comment: What does your core data stack look like? how many contexts do you have? are you using child and parent contexts? are you using NSPersistent​Container?

Comment: I have two contexts managedObjectContext & one more child managedObjectContext and not NSPersistentContainer, But I have tried saving using both those contexts and saved both contexts in app delegate save context also, but still I get the same issue.

Comment: It is hard to diagnose without seeing the code, but my guess would be that there is a merge conflict with another context so it can't save to the store.  If it is a new project and not hard to change stuff I would recommend using NSPersistentContainer, only write using performBackgroundTask and treat the viewContext as readonly.  If  it an old project and hard to change the core-data stack I would try to set a merge policy for every context.

Comment: When, exactly is that code executed? Do you call it yourself or is it only called from `applicationWillTerminate`?

Comment: @TomHarrington: I call it myself after updating a model object context & also in applicationWillTerminate.

Comment: @All: My issue got resolved while I tried saving using "try managedObjectContext.saveToPersistentStore()". "saveToPersistentStore()" is provided by Restkit. Thanks for your help Friends.